# Elasticsearch Routing allocation awarness and shard allocation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster containing 10 nodes splited across 3 zones (`A`, `B`, `C`).

The ES configuration file contain:

```
cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force.zone.values = "A,B,C";
```

I have a single index (`index1`) containing `=~ 283674` docs with a size of `=~ 231MB`.
The setting for this index contain:

```
"number_of_replicas" : "2", "number_of_shards" : "5",
```

Shards seems correctly distributed across zone but within a single zone they are not evenly distributed (see table below, E.g. Zone C | S = shard, (P = Primary | S = Secondary)

What can I do to correctly distribute my shards?

```
++------+----------------------------------------------------+
||Zone A-----------------------------------------------------|
||       |                                                  ||
|| Node 1|  S1 (P)                                          ||
|| +-----------------------------------------------------+  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S2 (S)          S4 (S)                          ||
||       |                                                  ||
|| Node 2|                                                  ||
|| +-----------------------------------------------------+  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S0 (S)          S3 (S)                          ||
||       |                                                  ||
|| Node 3|                                                  ||
|-------+----------------------------------------------------|
||Zone B-----------------------------------------------------|
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S0 (P)                                          ||
|| Node 4|                                                  ||
|| +-----------------------------------------------------+  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S3 (P)          S4 (P)                          ||
|| Node 5|                                                  ||
|| +-----------------------------------------------------+  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S1 (S)          S2 (S)                          ||
|| Node 6|                                                  ||
|-------+----------------------------------------------------|
||Zone C-----------------------------------------------------|
||       |                                                  ||
||       |  S0 (S)   S1 (S)   S2 (P)   S3 (S)   S4 (S)      ||
|| Node 7|                                                  ||
|| +------------------------------------------------------+ ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
|| Node 8|                                                  ||
|| +------------------------------------------------------+ ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
|| Node 9|                                                  ||
|| +------------------------------------------------------+ ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       |                                                  ||
||       -                                                  ||
|| Node 10                                                  ||
|------------------------------------------------------------|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: are you using any kind of ui for elasticsearch cluster admin? (like elasticsearch-head)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by forcing the number of shard per host and changing the number of primary / secondary per index:

```
index.number_of_shards = "5";
index.number_of_replicas = "3";
index.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node = "2";
```

This results in 2 shards per node evenly distributed across zone.